# Please check my steps and reasoning for getting conditional variance of a random variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Please let me know if I am not confirming to the protocols here.
Learning Law of Iterated Expectations is a very slow and long process for me. I know the formulae, but I don't really understand it. Without it Crosssectional and panel data by Wooldridge is taking many, many years to master.

I think finally I am getting it. Please check:

$$Var(Y|X) = E[ (Y - E(Y|X))^2 | X]   = E(Y^2|X) - (E(Y|X))^2$$
First equality is definitional. Proof of second equality: Expanding the middle,
$$E[ (Y^2 + (E(Y|X))^2 - 2 Y E ((Y|X)) | X )$$
Since conditional expectation is a linear operator
$$= E[Y^2|X] + E [ E(Y|X)^2 |X] - 2 E [ Y E(Y|X) |X]$$

Given $X, E(Y|X)^2$  and $E(Y|X)$  are constants, they can be pulled out of outer expectations, OR using $E(Y) = E [ E(Y|X) ], $
$$ = E[Y^2|X] + (E(Y|X))^2 -2 (E(Y|X))^2$$. $$Var(Y|X) = E(Y^2|X) - (E(Y|X))^2$$

I am pretty confident of this, but please let me know if my arguments are incorrect.

Comment: Yes, correct, this is the usual decomposition of the variance, conditioning on $X$ makes no difference, except that all expectations are under the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$.